# GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor - Filter's can't agree on connection

Tags: directshow, mp4

I am attempting to publish some mp4 files with the GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor but it's not accepting the input from my camera (QuickCam
Orbit/Sphere AF).

I see that it has set the the sub type is set to MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL.
I can't seem to figure out a set of filters that will adapt to
successfully link the pins.  What do I need to do to successfully
adapt from my Capture pin to the multiplexor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/) multiplexes compressed data and your camera captures raw (uncompressed) video. You need to insert a compressor in between in order to deliver MPEG-4 compatible video into the multiplexer. That is, MPEG-4 Part 2 or MPEG-4 Part 10 AKA H.264 video compressor. The multiplexer filter itslef does not do data compression/encoding.